# Why is Lorentz symmetry considered sacred?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, lorentz-symmetry

In almost all particle physics theories (except some effective field theories) why is it assumed that the Lagrangian of the theory should be Lorentz invariant? What is wrong with theories that consider breaking of Lorentz symmetries in microscopic or high energy scales?

I know that being non-Lorentz invariant means that there is a preferred reference system but why can't a theory have local violations of this symmetry?

Comment: Of course a theory can violate Lorentz symmetry. It's just that in the context of high energy physics, this isn't necessary to explain any observations, and furthermore most of the time it _contradicts_ observations unless you make the violation sufficiently small/hidden.

Comment: If that's not the context in which you're working, knock yourself out! Feel free to add Lorentz violating terms. _Most_ QFTs people study have them.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/498863/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Thanks for the link!